# generate m-matrices of differnet lengths using foreach command

Tags: r, matrix, foreach

Take this simple worked example with dummy data:

```
ab <- c(1:500)
cd <- sample(1:100, 500, replace = T)
ef <- sample(1:10, 500, replace = T)
df1 <- data.frame(ab, cd, ef)

m <- 4
```

Now I want to use the `foreach` command to generate `m` matrices

Each matrix will vary by length using:

```
#size1 <- sample(50:60, 1)
#indices <- sample(1:500, size1)
#df2 <- df1[indices,]
```

I have not sure if how to generate the different matrices with the `foreach` command

```
Result = foreach(i=1:m,.combine=matrix(df2)) %do%{

  size1 <- sample(50:60, 1)
  indices <- sample(1:500, size1)

  df2 <- df1[indices,]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default of `foreach` is to save a list. The following code saves a list of matrices of different dimensions.

```
Result <- foreach(i=1:5) %do%{
  # randomly select number of rows and columns  
  random.rows <- sample(1:5, 1)
  random.columns <- sample(1:5, 1)
  # generate matrix out of this
  matrix(sample(1:100, random.rows*random.columns), random.rows)
}
```

The Result object is a list of length 5 with matrices whose sizes vary between 1X1 and 5X5.

Comment: thats great it seems to work, however I am unsure what structure it saves the list in. For example, when we givé `str(Result)` we see it looks very messy. Then we have to sort through commands like `Result[[1]][[1]][[2]]` and `Result[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]` to get our `i` matrices